# What kind of crankset to get for this bike?

Tags: road-bike, crankset, hybrid-bike

I have a Schwinn Volare 1300, bought from [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P0IN0K4).

So the pedal on my crank arm came off today, when I tried to screw it back on I noticed that the hole where the screw goes has become smooth and does not have the screw notches on it anymore.

I've taken to my local repair shop and they told me I will need a replacement crankset. I have contacted warranty and am waiting for a response (as the bike is only a month old now) but in case that does not follow through, can someone suggest a compatible crank set?

Here is a closer look:

[image]

I don't know much about bikes so am not sure what kind to order.

Comment: First of all i would recommend to take the bike to a LBS to check the whole bike assembly (if you don't want some other parts to break as fast).

Comment: Note that this failure is most likely due to riding the bike with a loose pedal, and the loose pedal was probably due to improper assembly -- failure to tighten the pedal properly.  Or else when you initially installed the pedal you cross-threaded it.  The wear on the crank arm clearly shows that the pedal was loose for some time.

Comment: Did you assemble it - did you fit up the pedals ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a poorly assembled bike to me - I reckon its a warranty job if it came with pedals installed.

If you installed the pedals yourself, then you didn't do them up tight enough, and they've stripped the threads.... though a month is quite quick for that to happen.

Are you sure the pedals and the cranks had compatible threads?  Not a 9/16" and 1/2" mashed together with force?

To answer your question - you need a ruler.  It *looks* like a 175mm long alloy crank with a 5 leg spider.  If the warranty doesn't cover it, you'll need to remove the crank, and take it to a LBS.

Tools you'll need:

- Crank Puller
- 14mm socket to get the nut/bolt out of the middle.
- Whatever fitting the five chain bolts have - possibly a hex head/allen or maybe torx.

Or get the LBS to do the job, and to give the whole bike a once-over for safeties sake too.  I see in the Amazon link comments like "returned, pedal wouldn't thread in the hole."

Comment: The "pedal wouldn't thread into hole" could easily be because people aren't aware that the left hand pedal is reverse threaded.

Comment: This is the right-hand pedal. But still, if the bike has platform pedals right and left pedal are similar and can be screwed into the opposite cranks. Messing up the threads on both sides!

Comment: I'm also guessing that the pedals were on the wrong side and forced to thread in. With some of the cheaper cranks, the metal is soft enough.  I received a bike like that and had to re-tap the crank arms.  Fortunately it worked for me but re-tapping doesn't always do the trick.